# Laravel custom error messages for same rule used twice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create different custom error messages on the same rule used **twice or more** in my Laravel 5.0 validator method.

```
$messages = [ 'exists'    => 'The order finished',
              'exists'    => 'The order belong to another user.' ];   
$validator = Validator::make( ['order_id' => $order_id], 
                              ['order_id' => "required|exists:t_orders,channel_id,finished,0|exists:t_orders,channel_id,user_id,$user_id"], 
$messages);
```

However, whichever order the validation applies, only the last custom error message is returned.

Is there a way I use the same rule twice or more times and create different custom error messages for each?

Answer (score 1):

Use the validator again with different sets of rules or messages.

```
$rules1 = [
 'field' =>'exists:table,column',
];

$rules2 = [
 'field' =>'exists:another_table,another_column',
];

$messages1 = ['field.exists' =>'The order finished'];
$messages2 = ['field.exists' => 'The order belongs to another user'];

$validator1 = Validator::make($input, $rules1, $messages1);
$validator2 = Validator::make($input, $rules2, $messages2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about array in php, in $messages variable you basically have one key, If you dd($messages); below the $messages variable then you'll see It just have on key and it's the second one. If you put two key for message array like following code down below, the you will be fine.

```
$messages = [ 'exists'    => 'The order finished',
    'existsTwo'    => 'The order belong to another user.' ];   
$validator = Validator::make( ['order_id' => $order_id], 
    ['order_id' =>"required|exists:t_orders,channel_id,finished,0|existsTwo:t_orders,channel_id, user_id,$user_id"], $messages);
```